# Selenium Firefox Frame issue

Tags: selenium, firefox, webdriver

When I am finding the frames in Firefox browser I'm not getting the option of "This frame " option is not available. I am using Firefox version 48.0.2564.109 with Selenium.
Please help me to resolve this resolve.

Thanks in advance
Prathap Prath

Comment: Please post your complete error message + any relevant source.

Comment: html source, your code, give us some information...

Comment: What error have you got? Please provide details error

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are trying to switch between frames. There is no such thing as option "This frame". You can switch using one of the following methods

```
// via frame name or id as appears in the html <frame id="id" name="name">
driver.switchTo().frame("id");

// via frame index
driver.switchTo().frame(index);

// via located WebElement
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement());
```

And to switch back from the frame use

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```